# css issue taking extra space

Tags: html, css

I am using html and css. i am stuk with some issue.

[here is my link](http://rapidplumb.mobileedge.com.au/)
it is taking some extra white spaces. i used casurel plugin for  testinmonial. This page is showing extra empty space at footer. i don't want extra white space. this problem is due to testimonial section.

i tried to remove height under ul but still it causing problem. it doesnot showing content properly if i change the height .

Can you tell me where is my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `overflow: hidden;` for `#newsticker-demo` because your text is flowing out of the carousel.

Also you've `height: 100px;` for `#footer`